# Paragraph in HTML will not clear

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've worked on a small HTML file that calculates change in RPM and Pitch for DJing (since increasing the RPM of a record changes the pitch as well). However, in my code below the "p" named "Output" will not reset when I press the "Display" button. What am I doing wrong?

When I repeatedly press the "display" button without entering anything in the text boxes, the <p> called "Output" shows "One or more fields is blank" over and over again when it should only output that once.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<head>
<title>Pitch and RPM Calculator</title>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
var message = "<ul>"; 
var msg_aux = ""; 

function display() 
{
    var d_rpm = 0; 
    var d_p = 0; 
    var v_i = document.form1.yourname.value.replace(/\s/g, "").split(',').join('.'); 
    var v_f = document.form1.address.value.replace(/\s/g, "").split(',').join('.'); 
    var p_p = document.form1.phone.value.replace(/\s/g, "").split(',').join('.'); 
    document
    
    if ((v_i == "") || (v_f == "") || (p_p == ""))
    {
     msg_aux = "<b>One or more fields is blank. </b>"; 
    }
    else if (isNaN(v_i) || isNaN(v_f) || isNaN(p_p))
    {
     msg_aux = "<b>All inputs must be <i>numbers. </i></b>"; 
    }
 else
    {
     if ((document.form1.yourname.value <= 0) || 
      (document.form1.address.value <= 0))
        {
         msg_aux = "<b>BPM must be positive. </b>"; 
        }
        else
        {
         d_rpm = Math.round(100000000 * (v_f / v_i - 1)) / 1000000; 
            d_p = Math.round(100000000 * (Math.pow(2, p_p / 12) - v_f / v_i)) / 1000000; 
      msg_aux = "<ul><li><b>Percent RPM Change: </b>" + d_rpm + 
       "</li><li><b>Percent Pitch Change: </b>" + d_p + "</li>"; 
        }
    }
    message += msg_aux; 
    message += "</ul>"; 
    document.getElementById("Output").innerHTML = message; 
}

function clear()
{
 $("#Display").click(function() {
     $("#Output").html("");
 }); 
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload = "empty()">
<h1>Pitch Calculator</h1>
Enter the following information. When you press the Display button,
the data you entered will be displayed below. 
<form name="form1">
 <p>
     <b>Initial BPM:</b> <input TYPE="TEXT" SIZE="20" NAME="yourname" required />
 </p>
 <p>
     <b>Final BPM:</b> <input TYPE="TEXT" SIZE="30" NAME="address" required />
 </p>
 <p>
     <b>Pitch change (semitones): </b> <input TYPE="TEXT" SIZE="15" NAME="phone" required>
 </p>
 <p>
  <input type="button" value="Display" onClick="clear(); display();" />
  <input type="button" value="Clear" onClick="clear(); " />
 </p>
</form>
<p id="Output"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Side note: You might want to define the `empty()` function which you're calling `onload` of `body`

Comment: In your clear(), you're assigning a click handler, not actually clearing anything. You also need to rename the function, because for me, the function won't get called unless I do that. I guess `clear` is a reserved word. As for the message appearing over and over again, you keep appending text to `message`. You need to clear it in between.

Comment: The language attribute in your script tag is deprecated. Also, since html5 came out, you can drop type="text/javascript". You also don't need to set an listener on $("#Display").click() when you specify onClick in html.

Comment: I think I got it.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing in the clear function, is saying that when someone clicks on #Display, then you should clear the content of #Output. Since the clear function is already assigned to the related click events, just clear the content!

What you need I think is this:

```
function clear()
{
    $("#Output").html("");
}
```

The problem with yours, is that you'll have no idea if the `$("#Output").html("");` bit is executed before or after `display()`... Or if it's executed at all!

I mean, at the beginning you have an handler linked to the click event, which executes clear and display.

Once clear is executed the first time, then you have two click handlers on on display: one that executed clear and display, and one that effectively clears the content. But after the first clear, you'll have 3 event handlers linked to the click event! Every time you execute that clear, you add another event handler, and we have no idea in which order they're executed.

Also, check the 6th line of the display function - I think that's a typo.

Answer (score 0):

the variable `message` is global. You never clear it. Try to declare it locally and you should be fine.

Also, `clear` does not seem to be accepted as a function name. Here's a jsfiddle with a working solution https://jsfiddle.net/oxw9t5pa/3/